# scss style sheets issue rails 3.1

Tags: stylesheet, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

my projects.css.scss file looks like the bellow one,

```
// Place all the styles related to the Projects controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/

$right-container-background: #3BBFCE;
$right-container-padding: 2px;

.right-container{
    background-color: $right-container-background;
    color: white;
    padding-left: $right-container-padding;
    padding-right: $right-container-padding;
 }
```

It says that all styles will be automatically added to your application.css.

But I am not able to use it without importing to application.css
i.e.

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import "projects.css.scss";
@import "partners.css.scss";
```

So, while i'm in the  projects section of my view, is it not going to load all the .scss file imported in application.css ?

Comment: Could you add the whole `application.css`?

Comment: i already provided my application.css in the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `application.css` in rails 3.1 contains the following lines:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

You should re-add them if you want the default behaviour of including everything.

Comment: @KamrulHassan could you accept my answer then? You should also get back to your other questions and accept the solutions. It's clearer for other people that could come on this page and it gives you reputation ;-)